# AppleTV + Swift + MP4 + Xcode? How to show a .mp4 inside xcodeproj?

Tags: xcode, swift, video, apple-tv

how would I go about using Swift & AppleTV4 to display a video that is inside the XcodeProj? Can I use the AVPlayer to also play an Mp3 later?

This is what I have:

```
 import UIKit
 import AVFoundation
 import AVKit
 import MediaPlayer

 class ViewController: UIViewController {
let videoplayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: "file.mp4")!)
let audioplayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: "file.mp3")!)


@IBOutlet weak var Buttonizer: UIButton!

@IBAction func ButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    videoplayer.play()
    audioplayer.play()

  // let videoplayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4")!)        
}
and the rest.. (viewDidLoad stuff)
```

I tried to run AVPlayer with an external mp4, but the videoplayer.play() simply crashes with a breakcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to play a video in AVPlayer:

```
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType:"mp4")!
    let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()
```

Comment: Roel: I tried that inside the button, and inside viewDidLoad() - but all I get is a blurred background. Am I missing something? Should it be loaded into a secondary ViewController.. or?

Comment: wow Roel, it really does work. I will try and modify it to play a MP3 file instead. Also, is there some method of killing the videoplayer screen after it finishes? Because it seems that if I just keep pressing "Enter" (I'm running this in the simulator), it will keep playing another and another and another on top of eachother. :)

Comment: You can wrap the video in a playerItem and register for notifications with: NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "yourSelector:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: yourPlayerItem)

Comment: Interestingly, I get this: ERROR:    >aqme> 718: MEMixerChannel::EnableProcessor: failed to open processor type 0x705f6571  in the console everytime I launch a video or an audio.. Is that ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99244/discussion-between-roel-koops-and-esaruoho).